# DatePickerDialog how to no show the calendar just a spinner?

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I want to create a DatePickerDialog like this :

```
mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, null /* listener */, 2000/* year */, 1/* month */, 1/* dayOfMonth */);
```

but with spinner like this :

[image]

i try to set this in the xml:

```
  <style name="MyDatePicker" parent="@android:style/Widget.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:calendarViewShown">false</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"> 
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePicker</item>
  </style>
```

but didn't work :(

Answer (score 3):

I use this style to get the spinner Date picker:

```
<style name="MySpinnerDatePickerStyle" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MySpinnerDatePicker</item>
</style>

<style name="MySpinnerDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This works, but I'm curious to know why a style is necessary and why we can't just set datePickerMode on the DatePicker in XML.

Answer (score 1):

Try make dialog with this:

```
DatePickerDialog dialogDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
            dialogDatePicker.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
            return dialogDatePicker;
```

UPDATE:

The `setCalendarViewShown(false);` is depreated so you need to set datePickerMode as spinner using xml like this:

```
<DatePicker
    ...
    android:datePickerMode="spinner" />
```

Comment: @Jack and if you add this **dialogDatePicker.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(true);**

Comment: but i don't use any xml :( i create the datepicker dinamiqually :(

Comment: @Jack  So probably you need to do this, create a xml with the datepicker dialog and create an dialog with custom layout, if you want I can update my answer with the explanation using code.

Comment: but i abolutely need to create the DatePickerDialog dynamiqually like this:  mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, null /* listener */, 2000/* year */, 1/* month */, 1/* dayOfMonth */); i think i just need to edit the style instead no ?

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been 4 years but I just wanna post the answer to help others.        android:calendarViewShown="false"

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/textInputDataPicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/myDatePicker"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:calendarViewShown="false" />
```

This shows only spinner.